# Code is just stuck on inputting a bunch of numbers

Tags: c++

Whenever the program runs, and I input the two numbers(m and n), nothing happens and I'm able to keep on entering numbers.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    int m, n;

    cin >> m;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = m; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int sumofnum;
        int num = i;
        while (num)
        {
            sumofnum += pow(num % 10, 3);
            num / 10;
        }

        if (sumofnum == i)
        {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec.at(i) << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (num)
{
    sumofnum += pow(num % 10, 3);
    num / 10;
}
```

loops forever since `num` never changes<sup>(a)</sup> (and is presumably non-zero).  The second line of the loop should be:

```
num /= 10; // or "num = num / 10".
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The expression `num / 10` (like the expression `42`) is perfectly valid C++ in that it's *evaluated* then thrown away.